# how to grab two faces towards together

Tags: faces

I'm trying to move two faces towards each other but just go along one direction

[image: blender]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't really how *Transform* ( <kbd>G</kbd>) works - it sounds like you want *Scale* ( <kbd>S</kbd>).

With both faces selected, use  <kbd>S</kbd> and then <kbd>Y</kbd>. Entering a numerical value or moving your cursor will scale the two faces relative to each other along the Y-axis, which will either move them closer or farther apart.

Read up on the [difference between Move, Rotate, and Scale](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/mesh/transform/basic.html).